# Printing subsets of a small list of numbers using Java

Tags: java, recursion, nodes, subset

I believe I understand this problem enough to satisfy requirements. I'm able to sum up the contents of each subset to produce a total. But I'm curious how I could get it to display the contents of each subset before displaying the subset's total. Here is my code:

```
public void theSum(Node currentNode, int total){
    if (currentNode.getNext() == null){
        System.out.println(total;
    }
    else {
        theSum(currentNode.next, total + currentNode.getInt());
        theSum(currentNode.next, total);
    }
}
```

I tried placing a few print statements but I'm not quite sure how to piece this code together so that it displays the subsets themselves, without any repetitions. I believe the logic works since it prints each sum only once, and judging by my scribbles on paper it's printing each unique subset's sum. I just want to be able to print the subsets themselves as well. Is it possible with the way I've done this recursively?

Let's assume my simple list is {5, 6, 7}. Assume that each integer in the list is stored into consecutive nodes in a linked list. Here is how I attempted to display the subsets:

```
public void theSum(Node currentNode, int total){
        if (currentNode.getNext() == null){
            System.out.println(total);
            System.out.print(currentNode.getData());
        }
        else {
            System.out.print(currentNode.getData());
            theSum(currentNode.next, total + currentNode.getData());
            theSum(currentNode.next, total);
        }
    }
```

It seems to be returning results that are somewhat correct, although the subsets are not completely displayed the way I'd like them to be and there are some that are either incomplete or wrong. The results returned are:

1236
03
034
01
0235
02
033
00
0

The method is called like so:

```
theSum(list.head.getNext(), 0);
```

head is a node that has no data in it. So head.getNext() returns the node containing the first item in the list, which in this example is the integer 5. The second parameter is the initial total, which is 0.

Thanks for any tips. I've seen some questions asking for similar things regarding subsets. Since it appears that my method is successfully calculating the subset sums, I just want to know how exactly (if it's even possible) to place some print statements so that I can get each subset displayed along with the subset's sum to the right if possible. Example:

5 + 6 + 7 = 18

Comment: Consider editing your question to include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can more clearly see what you are working with unless you expect very general answers. (Use public members instead of getters and setters, an extremely minimal `main` method, etc...)

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to see if your linked-list chains are even correct?  Then step through TheSum recursions to watch the subset members and how they are getting summed?

Comment: have tried using the debugger to get a feel for how the recursion is working. I think the linked-list chains are correct - by that I assume you mean that the linked-list is actually holding the values I supply in the order I supply them. I'll take a closer look at my subset members to see how they are getting summed. Given that you're asking, I'm assuming that something is wrong with the logic and it isn't actually summing correctly? @cybermike

Comment: No ... I don't really know since I cannot debug it myself.  But that is the essence of debugging and being a good programmer.  When something does not work, I closely debug step-by-step, watching all the variables, and see where something is going wrong.  You have example subsets that are failing; put only one *small* subset into your code that you know fails, then step through your code and the recursion see why your code is failing.

Comment: Thank you @cybermike

I'll definitely give that a more thorough try.